# Any way to declare happen-before relatioship in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have some validation code that should run on server startup and make sure various conditions are met so whoever deploys the server don't messes up the DB or start the server with bad security configurations etc. To do that I created a bean

```
@Component
public class ApplicationStartupConditionsValidationBean {

    static class ServerInitializationError extends Error{
        public ServerInitializationError(String msg){
            super(msg);
        }
    }


    private Environment springEnv;
    private String datasourceURL;
    private String ddlAuto;

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Autowired
    public ApplicationStartupConditionsValidationBean(Environment springEnv) throws Exception {
        this.springEnv = springEnv;
        this.datasourceURL = springEnv.getProperty("spring.datasource.url");
        this.ddlAuto = springEnv.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto");
        validateStartupConditions();
    }

    public boolean isDBLocal(){
        return datasourceURL.startsWith("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:");

    }

    private String disallowedParamMsg(String optionName, String optionValue){
        return  "option " + optionName + "=" + optionValue + " not allowed in production";
    }

    private void reject(String msg) throws ServerInitializationError{
        String rejectionMsg = "startup conditions validation failed with msg: " + msg;
        logger.error(rejectionMsg);
        throw new ServerInitializationError(rejectionMsg);
    }

    private void reject(String paramName, String paramValue) throws ServerInitializationError{
        reject(disallowedParamMsg(paramName, paramValue));
    }

    private void validateDatasourceParams(){
        if(!isDBLocal() &&
                !ddlAuto.equals("validate")){
            reject("ddl-auto", ddlAuto);
        }
    }

    public void validateStartupConditions() throws Exception{
        logger.info("validating startup conditions");
        validateDatasourceParams();
        // more validation logic...

        logger.info("startup conditions validation succeeded, proceeding with boot");
    }

}
```

The way I would have wanted to use this class is to define what beans this must come before. In the example here I would have wanted to make sure this bean would be created before the DataSource bean is created, so that "ddl-auto=create" doesn't slip in production. I Know about the @DependsOn annotation but I would have wanted to do the reverse, and declare that this bean @HappensBefore a list of other beans. Is there any way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: You are aware that this wouldn't be foolproof? If someone were to add a `persistence.xml` for JPA the ddl creation could be defined there and not in properties. If one uses multiple datasources the property names would be different as well. If you really want to prevent DDL creation in production use a different user for DDL management (use that with something like flyway) and for DML statements (for use with hibernate to read/insert/modify data).

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to spring/spring-boot and wasn't sure if that would cover all cases. In my tests it covered the cases where the setting is set via an environment variable or the properties file. You're right about using schema management we are planning integrate with Liquibase down the road. I also configured different users as you suggested but the app still needs privileges to delete rows. However the question was more general, there's more validation logic that needs to be executed before some other beans are created.

Comment: You always need privileges to INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE but you can seperate those from ALTER/CREATE/DROP statements hence 2 users with different privileges. But as stated this won't cover all your bases (your current solution) as there are multiple ways one could set the properties and you are only checking 1 way. If you want to check somethings your safest bet is the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run code before "normal" beans get created, you can use a [`BeanFactoryPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-extension-factory-postprocessors).

To declaratively add additional dependencies among beans, you could also use a [`BeanPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-extension-bpp), but that sounds needlessly cumbersome for your use case.

Comment: This issue isn't a priority in my company so I won't have time to check if it solves the problem soon, but from reading into it this seems like BeanFactoryPostProcessor is the most accurate answer. So if anyone else is looking for something similar, if you need all your validation code in the same place BeanFactoryPostProcessor is probably the way to go, however if you just want validation consider providing your own implementation for critical beans and validating whatever you need in the constructor or using the bean validation api if it suits your needs.